# Unable to start process C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe. The web server request failed with status code 502. Error in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I am facing a strange issue while building a solution which has web projects. I get the error below. Any solution or thought on it.

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to run an asp.net core app with IIS ?

Comment: same problem here, no idea how to solve

Comment: @andrepaulo try checking your web.config file. This was cause of issue for me. I removed unnecessary settings from it and application worked.

Comment: I got similar error (status code 503), but in my case port number 59090 was unavailable. Changing port to different number solved issue.

Answer (score 9):

Fixed by adding `forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"` in the web.config file.

```
 <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" stdoutLogEnabled="false" />
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module

Comment: This has fixed my problem too. I have no idea why it has happened. All worked perfectly yesterday and broke today. Strange things happen..

Comment: This fixed my issue as well. I added a web.config to a .NET core web api project so that I could put it in IIS. After that I could no longer run from code in IIS express until I added the above line.

Comment: It did not help

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue here

[image: Error Information]

**How I fix**

(1) Open Event Log. I noticed that there is a warning: '**Static compression is being disabled**'.

[image: Event Viewer Image]

(2) Follow the 2 links to fix this issue

- https://forums.iis.net/t/1195656.aspx?The+directory+specified+for+caching+compressed+content+is+invalid+Static+compression+is+being+disabled+
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc735199(v=ws.10)

(3) Open **TOOLS** -> **Options** -> **Projects and Solutions**

Enable 'Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express for web sites and projects' **(My system is 64 bit)**

[image: Tool Settings in VS2017]

---

I am not very sure what happen exactly. But this helps me to fix this issue. Hope it can help you as well.

Comment: This option didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that my web.config file got changed. It had configurations set for deployment which were not available to me. Restoring the web.config file fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the .vs folder has fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an old question and most of the answers look ok. To resolve the similar issue, I added AllowedServerVariables in  vs -> ->config ->applicationhost.config file as below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you have dotnet core >=2.2 just add the following to your project

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

You possibly have a url reservation configured for that particular endpoint that could be conflicting. You can see the list of these by running the following command at an elevated cmd prompt:

`netsh http show urlacl`

You can delete the offending one like so:

`netsh http delete urlacl http://+:59090/`